# Efficient way to create masking kreg values

Tags: optimization, x86, simd, avx512

One of the benefits of Intel's AVX-512 extension is that nearly all operations can be masked by providing in addition to the vector register a *kreg* which specifies a mask to apply to the operation: elements excluded by the mask may either be set to zero or retain their previous value.

A particularly common use of the kreg is to create a mask that excludes N contiguous elements at the beginning or end of a vector, e.g., as the first or final iteration in a vectorized loop where less than a full vector would be processed. E.g., for a loop over 121 `int32_t` values, the first 112 elements could be handled by 7 full 512-bit vectors, but that leaves 9 elements left over which could be handled by masked operations which operate only on the first 9 elements.

So the question is, given a (runtime valued) integer `r` which is some value in the range 0 - 16 representing remaining elements, what's the most efficient way to load a 16-bit kreg such that the low `r` bits are set and the remaining bits unset? `KSHIFTLW` seems unsuitable for the purpose because it only takes an immediate.

Comment: I assume/hope `(~0) >> (16-r)` compiles efficiently to 32-bit MOV-immediate + SHRX + KMOVW.  Err I guess a sub or neg in there, too, and x86 shifts only mask their count by `&31`, not `&15` for 15-bit shifts.  Perhaps a better sequence on Intel CPUs is `xor`-zero / BTS / DEC / KMOVW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54809132/2439725).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BMI2 `bzhi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bzhi) does exactly what you want: Zero High Bits Starting with Specified Bit Position.  Every CPU with AVX512 so far has BMI2.

```
__mmask16 k = _bzhi_u32(-1UL, r);
```

This costs 2 instructions, both single-uop: mov-immediate and `bzhi`.  It's even single-cycle latency. (Or 3 cycles on KNL)

- For `r=0`, it zeros all the bits giving 0.
- For `r=1`, it leaves only the low bit (bit #0) giving 1
- For `r=12`, it zeros bit #12 and higher, leaving `0x0FFF` (12 bits set)
- For `r>=32` BZHI leaves all 32 bits set (and sets CF)

The INDEX is specified by bits 7:0 of the second source operand

If you had a single-vector-at-a-time cleanup loop that runs after an unrolled vector loop, you *could* even use this every loop iterations, counting the remaining length down towards zero, instead of a separate last-vector cleanup.  It leaves all bits set for high lengths.  But this costs 2 uops inside the loop, including port 5 `kmovw`, and means your main loop would have to use masked instructions.  This only works for r<=255 because it only looks at the low byte, not the full integer index.  But the `mov reg, -1` can be hoisted because `bzhi` doesn't destroy it.

---

PS. Normally I think you'd want to arrange your cleanup to handle 1..16 elements, (or 0..15 if you branch to maybe skip it).  But the full 17-possibility 0..16 makes sense if this cleanup also handles small lengths that never enter the main loop at all, and len=0 is possible.  (And your main loop exits with length remaining = 1..16 so the final iteration can be unconditional)